# Showing error while opening main.xml file

Tags: java, android

I am starting to learn android. I have done everything as mentioned in the guide, and I tried the hello android example.

But I just can´t open the main.xml file to edit, it gives me this error: `Could not initialize class java.awt.Font`. I am on Linux kde.

I don´t know what I should do, and please avoid any solutions that use `sudo` as I am not authorized to do that as I am using the university PC.

Comment: This is not a java problem but a text editor (or IDE) problem. You should give your editor name and tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an old eclipse, maybe in combination with a non-Sun JDK which is common in older linux:es.